# Two Equivalent Equations for the Zeros of the Jacobi Theta Function?

Tags: elliptic-functions, theta-functions

I'm trying to find the 0's for the Jacobi theta function with characteristic:
$$
\vartheta_{a,b}(z, \tau) :=\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty} e^{\pi i (n + a)^{2} \tau + 2 \pi i(n + a)(z + b)},\quad a,b \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

In Mumfords Lectures on Theta, the 0's are given at the points:
$$(a + p +1/2)\tau + (b + q + 1/2) $$ where $p,q$ are integers. 
OOH, a previous question on Stackexchange:
[the zeros of theta function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380036/the-zeros-of-theta-function) gives the zeroes as being at: $$z=\!(p-\!\tfrac 12\!-\!a)\tau+\!\tfrac 12\!-b-q$$
Unfortunately, I can't follow the proof well enough in the latter to check for a mistake, but from what I can tell the latter actually gives the 0's of $\vartheta_{-a,-b}$. Which of these equations gives the correct 0's of $\vartheta_{a,b}$?

Comment: Your link finds some zeros but it doesn't prove there are no more which I think needs [Jacobi triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product). What you can do is, fixing $x$, use the transformation law of the product to find the coefficients of its Laurent series in $y$, they will be $x^{n^2}f(x)$ with $f$ holomorphic on $|x|<1$ thus proving your claim about the zeros.

Comment: The MSE zeros are correct. You should check if the Mumford theta definition is the same.

Comment: @Somos The Mumford definition is verbatim the definition used in the MSE post, so I'm not sure how this is possible. The Mumford zeros are also used [here](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~klevtsov/lecture9.pdf) on page 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how the Mumford claim is wrong, but simple
calculations demonstrate that it is. For example, [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) code:

```
e(x) = exp(Pi*I*x);
Thn(n,z,t,a,b) = e((n+a)^2*t) * e(2*(n+a)*(z+b));
{Th(z,t,a,b) = suminf(n=0,Thn(n,z,t,a,b)) +
               suminf(n=1,Thn(-n,z,t,a,b))};
a=.2; b=.2 ; t=1.*I;
print([Th((+a+.5)*t+b+.5,t,a,b), Th((-a+.5)*t-b+.5,t,a,b)])
[-0.766570202+4.83993375*I, 0.E-9+0.E-9*I]
```

It could be simple sign error which is easy to make.